# Who can not sit in middle if $A$ is not near $B$ and $C$ is beside $D$

Tags: combinatorics

Five people, $A,B,C,D,E$, are sitting in a row. $A$ is not near $B$. $C$ is beside $D$. Who can NOT sit in the middle?

There are $5!=120$ combinations, that much I understood. But how do I answer the question above?

Comment: This seems to be a logic question. Though you could list all 120 possibilities and eliminate the ones that don't work (not recommended).

Comment: What does "is not near" mean? "Is not next to?"  "Has at least two people in between?"

Comment: Define "near"..

Comment: You can start by assuming that "combining" $C$ and $D$ into one giant person, which would then reduce the number of possibilities to $2 \cdot 4! = 48$. (The arrangement for $C$ and $D$ could be $CD$ or $DC$, which is why the $2$ is there, and we now only have to consider sitting four "groups" of people, which is why the $4!$ is there.) Of course, even that is a lot, so it's advised that you narrow it down even further by considering $A$ and $B$.

Comment: sorry..near means next to or A is not beside B.  thanks

Comment: This is not a probability question, so I replaced the probability  with a combinatorics tag.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ can sit in the middle: $CDAEB$

$B$ can sit in the middle: $AEBCD$

$C$ can sit in the middle: $AECDB$

$D$ can sit in the middle: $AEDCB$

$E$ cannot sit in the middle, because if $C$ is beside $B$, that forces $A$ to be beside $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Number the seats 1,2,3,4,5.

We can eliminate the possibility that $a$ and $b$ are in seat 2 and 4 respectively, as that would mean $c$ would not be beside $d$.

**HINT** Check for all possibilities of $c$ sitting beside $d$.